# Saving data with medium-editor-rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, medium-editor

I have install medium-editor-rails gem following this https://github.com/marjinal1st/medium-editor-rails

its working perfectly to show the edit box but don't know how to save data through model

Here is the view div in show page

```
<div class="editable">
  <%= @micropost.content %>
</div>
```

And corresponding Js

```
var editor = new MediumEditor('.editable', {
  anchorInputPlaceholder: 'Type a link',
  buttons: ['bold', 'italic', 'quote'],
  diffLeft: 25,
  diffTop: 10,
  firstHeader: 'h1',
  secondHeader: 'h2',
  delay: 1000,
  targetBlank: true
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to save your data, you should add the `<div>` in `_form.html.erb` instead of `show.html.erb` file of your model Micropost. Here is what it could look like:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :content, html: { id: "content" } %>
<div class="editable" data-field-id="content"><%= @micropost.content.html_safe %></div>
```

The first line passes the data `:content` when you hit the save/submit button in your form.

Also, add the following function at the end of your JS.

```
$('.editable').bind('input propertychange', function() {
  $("#micropost_" + $(this).attr("data-field-id")).val($(this).html());
});
```

Not sure how this works. My guess is that it tracks the changes and helps in saving. Someone with knowledge of JS can actually help explain this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to monitor changes to the editor, you can subscribe to the custom `editableInput` event that MediumEditor exposes.  It will fire whenever a change occurs within the editor, regardless of whether it comes from typing, cutting/pasting, or changing the formatting of the text.

Also, you can get the content of the editor by either calling `editor.getContent(index)` or `editor.serialize()`.  MediumEditor supports having multiple elements passed into it, so these methods are built to work regardless of how many editor elements you have.

`editor.getContent(index)` takes an `index` argument which indicates the index of the element you want the content of.  If you just have a single element you're using with the editor, you can just call `editor.getContent(0)`.

`editor.serialize()` will create a JSON object containing key-value pairs for each of the elements within the editor.  The key will be the `id` attribute of the editor element, and the value will be the trimmed `innerHTML` of the element.

Tying all of this together, you can use the sample code for the `.erb` as mentioned by @bean above and then use this for the javascript:

```
editor.subscribe('editableInput', function (event, editorEl) {
    var $micropost = $("#micropost_" + editorEl.getAttribute('data-field-id'));
    $micropost.val(editor.getContent(0));
});
```